# Can anyone please give pdf link for Brahma Sutra Bhashya of Shri Madhwacharya in English or Kannada?

Tags: vedanta, translation-request, brahma-sutras, dvaita, madhvacharya

Is a PDF version of Shri Madhwacharya Brahma Sutra Bhashya in English or Kannada available?

Comment: Can you check whether [this](https://srimadhvyasa.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/brahmasutrabhashya3.pdf) is a Kannada Translation or just a Transliteration?

Comment: @Pandya its transliteration. Thanks for the effort tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: The source, nageshsonde.com is no more accessible. Following links to [January 2020's snapshot from Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20200121084816/http://nageshsonde.com)

nageshsonde.com is a good website which provides most of works of Anandatirtha (Madhwacharya) with English Translations.

Here is the book you're looking for: [**Brahma Sutra Bhashya English Translation**](http://web.archive.org/web/20200121084816/http://nageshsonde.com/Bramha-Sutra.html)

[image]

PDFs: [Part 1](http://web.archive.org/web/20200121084816/http://nageshsonde.com/images/Bramha-Sutra1.pdf), [Part 2](http://web.archive.org/web/20200121084816/http://nageshsonde.com/images/Bramha-Sutra2.pdf), [Part 3](http://web.archive.org/web/20200121084816/http://nageshsonde.com/images/Bramha-Sutra3.pdf), [Part 4](http://web.archive.org/web/20200121084816/http://nageshsonde.com/images/Bramha-Sutra4.pdf), [Part 5](http://web.archive.org/web/20200121084816/http://nageshsonde.com/images/Bramha-Sutra5.pdf), [Part 6](http://web.archive.org/web/20200121084816/http://nageshsonde.com/images/Bramha-Sutra6.pdf)

I didn't find the Kannada Translation.

Comment: Dude serIoisly I need to learn how to browse from you. Thanks a ton 

Comment: Links are not opening

Comment: @SanatanDarshan Thanks for reporting.

Comment: @SanatanDarshan Answer is updated to make the links working again :)

Answer (score 4):

The English translation of Vedanta/ Brahma Sutra is given [here](https://archive.org/details/BrahmasutraMadhvaEnglish/mode/1up?view=theater) with commentry of Sri Madhavacharya.

[image]